# Is it possible to make my own phi symbol?

Tags: fonts, symbols, math-fonts

I want a symbol like `\varphi` but more like the following picture:

[image]

as opposed to the current `\varphi`.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: OMG!....It's somewhat related to font cooking....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\varphi` symbol in the [Kerkis](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kerkis) font seems to match the shape you're looking for. The Kerkis text and math font can be loaded with the `kerkis` and `kmath` packages respectively.

You could also load only the `\varphi` symbol from Kerkis, like in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{letterskerkis}{OML}{mak}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathalpha}{letterskerkis}{"27}
\begin{document}
\( \varphi \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such a nice suggestion....